# Cross domain using JSONP jquery/ javascript in sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, jsonp

I need a great help to achieve the Cross domain functionality in SharePoint 2013 through Rest API + Ajax call.

To elaborate, In (SitecollectionA) team Site I am hosting the script to display the list items using script Editor. The source for the script is from (SitecollectionB) publishing site list.

I have tried the following code, but nothing(including .getJSON) worked.

Site CollectionA --URL : http://teams.theheart.com/team/CDTeam/SitePages/default.aspx
Site CollectionB --URL : http://icon.theheart.com/WorkTools/Organization/Claim/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Claims Links')/items?callback=?

Script Code 1:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

     //http://icon.theheart.com/WorkTools/Organization/Claim/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Claims Links')/items?callback=Mycallback 
     //http://icon.theheart.com/WorkTools/Organization/Claim/Lists/ClaimsLinks/AllItems.aspx?Getquote?callback=?
     //http://teams.theheart.com/team/CDTeam/SitePages/default.aspx?callback=?

  var requestUri = "http://icon.theheart.com/WorkTools/Organization/Claim/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Claims Links')/items?callback=?";

    //$.getJSON(requestUri,
                //function (Data){
        //alert(Data);
   //})
//.fail(
//function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
//alert('Fail ' + err);
//});


$.ajax({

  url: requestUri,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data){
    alert("Pass");
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
  alert('Fail ' + err);
  }

});




}); 

</script>
```

ErroR Details:

### On Internet Explorer:

### Message from webpage

### Fail Error: jQuery110208936579623092504_1436965753346 was not called

### OK

On Chrome :

**Refused to execute script from 'http://icon.theheart.com/WorkTools/Organization/Claim?Callback=jQuery110205155964728910476_1436965772075&_=1436965772076' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.**

Script Code 2:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

     //http://icon.theheart.com/WorkTools/Organization/Claim/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Claims Links')/items?callback=Mycallback 
     //http://icon.theheart.com/WorkTools/Organization/Claim/Lists/ClaimsLinks/AllItems.aspx?Getquote?callback=?
     //http://teams.theheart.com/team/CDTeam/SitePages/default.aspx?callback=?

  var requestUri = "http://icon.theheart.com/WorkTools/Organization/Claim/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Claims Links')/items?callback=?";

    //$.getJSON(requestUri,
                //function (Data){
        //alert(Data);
   //})
//.fail(
//function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
//alert('Fail ' + err);
//});




$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType:"application/javascript",
    success: function(data){
    },
error: function()
{
}

});


}); 

</script>
```

**Error: No Allow origin error though added the allow origin in header under ajax call**